# How can I install apps onto my 2nd partition of my SD Card?

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, link2sd

I created a 2nd partition on my SD card. It has the FAT32 file system. Then I used [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl=en) to create the mount scripts. In the settings, I changed the default install location to *External*. The below summary gives an overview of my storage capacity.

However, when I try to install an app from the Play store, I receive an *Insufficient storage* error message, despite having 94% free space on my 2nd partition.

How can I install apps directly onto my 2nd partition?

```
Internal /data (10% Free)
SD Card /mnt/sdcard (72% Free)
SD Card 2nd Part. /data/sdext2 (94% Free)
System /system (15% Free)
Cache /cache (97% Free)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better give up attempting to install apps on a FAT32 volume. Various issues will soon drive you mad. Format the 2nd partition to ext4 before doing anything else.

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me why? And will that solve my problem of insufficient storage? I am hesitating to reformat as I will lose all my installed apps. :-(

Comment: @orschiro You should first move some already installed apps to SD card. This will easily solve the problem.